# Should I have a constructor in my base class if it is only used by my subclass?

Tags: java

Say I have a parent class:

```
public class Foo
{
   // only needed for subclass
   public Foo(String a, String b, String c)
   {
      //initialize variables
   }

   // never used by subclass
   public Foo(SomeClass class)
   {
      //initialize variables
   }

   public String getValue()
   {
     return "abc";
   }
}
```

And another class:

```
public class Bar extends Foo
{
   public Bar(String a, String b, String c)
   {
      super(a, b, c); // nothing else special is needed, just a call to super
   }

   @Override
   public String getValue()
   {
     return "xyz";
   }
}
```

Should my base class even have a special constructor like this, or should I just use a default constructor in base?

Comment: If you are not going to use the constructor with no parameters, then just remove it

Comment: @fujy I guess my question was should I only define a default constructor in my parent class, or is it ok to have a constructor with 3 params that's only always going to be used by the subclass

Comment: Do you want to allow users to call that constructor? Does `new Foo("a", "b", "c");` make logical sense?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS technically users will never call that constructor from Foo class. But it's not like logically it doesn't make sense either. That's why I'm a bit conflicted

Comment: No, you can call `super()` (which is done implicitly anyway) or whatever, - the current child parameters need not be passed.

Comment: I wouldn't want callers to think that it's ok to use that constructor with 3 params to initialize base class I guess. So leaning more towards a default constructor

Comment: Yes, it is ok to have a constructor with 3 params that's only always going to be used by the subclass

Comment: This is what protected access is for, basically.

Answer (score 1):

I would use no `protected` access modifier (thanks @JonSkeet for the hint) in that constructor, meaning it can only be accessed by classes in the same package or sub-classes (regardless of which package they are in). At least it gives you some sort of "privacy" in regards to such a constructor.

```java
public class Foo
{
    // only needed for subclass
    protected Foo(String a, String b, String c)
    {
        //initialize variables
    }

    // never used by subclass
    public Foo(SomeClass class)
    {
        //initialize variables
    }

    public String getValue()
    {
        return "abc";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why restrict it to the same package? If the aim is for it to be used by subclasses, then surely `protected` is more suitable. We don't know anything about whether the subclasses are expected to be in the same package or not, based on the question. (I personally think it's a pity that protected access *also* allows non-subclass access within the same package, but that's a separate matter.)

Comment: That is true @JonSkeet and thanks for the hint, I will update my answer. And I agree with you, an access modifier that would only allow access to sub-classes would be great indeed.